#  VM terminated. Exit code=13

Tags: java, centos

Hi just now i changed to centos 5.7 i was installed java. I am sure about  that it is working well i checked it javac and java commands from terminal.But when i was trying to launch eclipse is says some says that

> A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be
>   available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found
>   after searching the following locations:
>   /home/seed/app/jre1.5.0_10/bin

.

When i was run `/eclipse -vm /home/seed/app/jre1.5.0_10/bin` command from terminal.If i open in eclipse from filesystem it  gives following error.

```
VM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /home/developer/Softwares/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash
-launcher /home/developer/Softwares/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/developer/Softwares/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.100.v20110505/eclipse_1407.so
-startup /home/developer/Softwares/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 68801a
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-jar /home/developer/Softwares/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
```

Comment: are you mixing 32 bit and 64bit ?  Say using 64bit eclipse exe with 32bit jre?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, turns out the shortcut made by the installer was set to 
`/eclipse/` instead of `/eclipse64/`.

Answer (score 0):

Open `eclipse.ini` and type the following at the beginning of the file.

```
-vm
/path/to/java/bin/javaw
```

Comment: I  was added same line in that file now this is the error A Java Runtime Environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK)
must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine
was found after searching the following locations:
/path/java/bin/javaw

Comment: That was an example. I didn't ask you to add the same line literally! Use your actual path to `javaw` command instead

Comment: I think it'll be `/home/seed/app/jre1.5.0_10/bin/javaw` in your case

Comment: there was no javaw in my java path in /usr/bin/ instead javaws is there i copied javaws path but still same problem

Comment: No, you should only use `java` or `javaw`. Try with `java` or else you will have to find the `javaw` inside a JDK installation. What you're seeing now is JRE.

Comment: i set java path i.e /usr/java/bin/java but still not resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Problem with incompatible eclise that is 32 bit and my machine is  64 bit finally i solved this By downloading 64 bit eclipse from :http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/SR1/eclipse-java-indigo-SR1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz